# regex javascript search for first two digits and make sure all characters are alpha afterward

Tags: javascript, regex

hoping for a quick answer to this
I have a string and I'm trying to match the first **two** numbers

```
var str = "aasd10aaaa";
```

after that I want to make sure that each character after the first two digits is an alpha character a-z

here's what I have so far

```
var str = "aasd10aaaa";    
var testIt = /[0-9]{2}[a-z]+/i
var test = testIt.test(str)
```

However if my string is

```
var str = "aasd101aaa";
```

however when I test the above string it still returns true even though it shouldn't because I only want the reg ex to match the first two digits; after the first two digits it should be all alpha characters.  I'm new to reg ex, can't figure out;  as always any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
var testIt = /(?:\D)\d{2}[a-z]+/i
```

`\D` means not number, If you just limit to `a-z`, then use `[a-z]`.

`(?:\D)` means match a non number char, but not catch in group.

Comment: thank you - I have much to learn about reg ex - I am trying to learn via this page http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re2.shtml but do not see : anywhere - thanks for your help

Answer (score 8):

```
var testIt = /^[^0-9]*?[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]+$/;
```

`[^0-9]*?` anything not containing digits.
`[0-9]{2}` two digits.
`[a-zA-Z]+` check for characters after the two digits are all word characters.

Comment: thanks for your answer razzak - it is the correct answer but xdazz had a solution before you so I accepted his as the answer but gave you an upvote ... I appreciate the help